# c# When the textbox text is null or empty error

Tags: c#, winforms, null

[image]

I want to when textbox1.text null or empty error happened, return to 0

Comment: Dont paste pictures of code. K thanks

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible extract of your code.

Answer (score 5):

In short, you should always validate user input with the `TryParse` style methods.

You should never **never** ***N̨͈̤̣͊͊́̃E̡͎̺̺̭̒̍̂̐̓V̢̱̓͒Ẻ̫͉̙̈́̽Ŕ̨͉̹̦͑̌̑́͟**  use `Convert` methods.

---

So, you could do something like this...

```
var r = byte.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out var tempR) ? tempR : 0;
var g = byte.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out var tempG) ? tempG : 0;
var b = byte.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out var tempB) ? tempB : 0;
```

Comment: I upvote this, could I know why not Convert method?

Comment: @Wei hi, nice seeing you again. Convert methods will break on invalid input and users are great at getting things wrong. `TryParse` methods will allow you to determine if the input is valid without unwinding the stack when an exception is thrown for the convert methods